# Bezout theorem for two varieties in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a Bezout theorem for any two varieties with complementary dimension in projective space? A statement stating the intersection number equals the product of their degree?
（In Hartshorne I.7.7, the proposition was only proved when one is a hypersurface.）

Comment: Yes! It is the product in the Chow ring of projective space. See Theorem 1.22 on p. 31 here: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf